# Angular: Convert a service function into an observable

Tags: angular, observable, webusb

Having spent some time trying to get my head around using observable's on service functions, I have decided to ask the question on here.

I have a service which is designed around WebUSB in order to make a connection to a device attached to the computer within the browser. The code works but it needs to be better, in that when it calls the function to connect, since it is a pure function, the code continues in the background within the controller regardless of whether or not a device is actually selected.

webSerialService.ts

```
// Grab and assign a port to the variables this.device.
requestPorts() {

    navigator.serial.requestPort(this.filters)
        .then(
            (result) => {

                this.device = result;

                // Open up the port.
                this.device.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("The user selected the cancel, no port was selected.");
            }
        );

    return this.device;
}
```

And the receiving controller code:

```
public connect() {

    // Let the user know they are about to do something.
    this.displayText = "-----";

    try {

        // Return the device selected.
        this.device = this.webSerialService.requestPorts();

    } catch (e) {

        console.log(e);
    }

    // Have we selected a port or not?
    if (this.webSerialService.device == false) {

        // Let the user know that no port was selected.
        this.displayText = "NO PORT";
    }
    else {
        // Let the user know they are connected.
        this.displayText = "Awaiting Data";
    }
}
```

The second part of the controller code, obviously executes without waiting for a device to be selected, which is not what I want, but expected. Having tried to turn the service function into an observable and then subscribing to it within the controller, I would get the error message when the "connect" function is fired:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
```

I amended the function definition within the server to:

```
requestPorts(): Observable<any> {
```

And then the controller code would be:

```
this.webSerialService.requestPorts().subscribe(data => {console.log(data)});
```

Which is where the aforementioned error would occur.

I've tried several various examples found on the internet and on StackOverflow, but I seem to be missing a crucial bit of understanding how Observables work and how to define them for functions.

Thank-you for any input and insight you can provide.

Comment: You should have to share this props: `this.device`, what is the props type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the `Observable` itself. The problem is that the moment you return `this.device`, it hasn't been assigned a value yet. It's `undefined`. Hence the error.

Try converting the `Promise` into an `Observable` like this instead:

```
import { from, map } from 'rxjs';

// ...

requestPorts(): Observable<any> {
   return from(navigator.serial.requestPort(this.filters)).pipe(
      map((result) => {
         this.device = result;
         this.device.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
         return this.device;
      })
   );  
}
```

Comment: That worked a treat, apart from the 'map' having to be imported from 'rxjs/operators'.

Comment: @JimGrant You must be using an older version of rxjs. I wrote this snippet in StackBlitz which installs the latest versions. As of v7.2.0 importing from 'rxjs/operators' is deprecated (See: https://rxjs.dev/guide/importing).